# Grabbing a non-english character in jexcelapi

Tags: java, excel, apache-commons, jexcelapi, apache-commons-lang

I have an excel sheet with some non-english characters in it and when I try to grab the contents via

```
sheet.getColumn(column)[row].getContents()
```

It returns the string with the replacement character \uFFFD instead of the non-english character which I was going to then translate to unicode using StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava.

```
//"L\u00F6schen" - correct
return StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava("Löschen"); 

//"L\uFFFDschen" - incorrect
return StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(sheet.getColumn(column)[row].getContents());

//"L�schen" - incorrect
System.out.print(sheet.getColumn(column)[row].getContents());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was really frustrating and it seems that jexcelapi is missing a lot of support.

Went with [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) instead and it worked great with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set encoding through WorkbookSettings when initializing Workbook.
For example:

```
WorkbookSettings settings = new WorkbookSettings();
settings.setEncoding("Your java charset name");
Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(source, settings);
```

Then getContents() method should correct content of cell